# Does A Function Like This Exist?

Tags: functions

I've been trying to figure out if there is a real function of the form
$$f(x) = 3 + \alpha \int_{2x}^1 f(t)f(t-2x) dt$$
such that $\alpha > \frac{3}{4}$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1.$
I've played around with a few ideas, in particular expanding the integral
$f$'s to be
$$f(x) = 3 + \alpha \int_{2x}^1 (3+\alpha \int_{2t}^1 f(s)f(s-2t)ds)
(3+\alpha \int_{2t-4x}^1 f(s)f(s-(2t-4x)) ds) dt,$$
But this seemed to me to be an unreasonable expansion. I have a feeling that
I may want to approach this problem by studying some properties of $f'(x),$
i.e. let
$$f'(x) = \alpha (f(1)f(1-2x)-f(2x)f(0)),$$
but is there somethnig that I could do with $f(1)$ and $f(0)$ to privde any
meaningful implications about $f$?